# Parent Floating Element won't resize with percent width child

Tags: css, layout, width, css-float

I have a floating parent div containing a child using `width: 30%`.

It seems this parent div won't resize if using percent as the width unit, but it works well when using px or ems.

Is there any way to make the parent div adjust its width when using `width: 30%` since I would like to have a fluid layout?

Please have a look at this example for more details:
http://jsfiddle.net/sBzYH/

```
<div class='percent container'>
    <div>
        <h3>width: 30%</h3>
        <p>
            When using the child div
            with percent width, the floating
            parent div keeps expading 100%.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class='pixel container'>
    <div>
        <h3>width: 100px</h3>
        <p>
            When using the child div 
            with pixel width, the floating
            parent div resizes accordingly.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean here - you're not setting a width on the parent `div`?

Comment: you're correct In this case I'm not because I would like it to adjust itself based on its contents width. Hence the `float: left`.

Comment: But it's content is going to be 30% of the width of what it is, every time you make the container smaller the content will get smaller too?

Comment: So in this case when setting the child div to 30% it automatically uses the parent as 100% so it can inherit the 30% out of it?

Comment: For the 30% width on the child element to have meaning, it's got to be 30% *of* *something*, this is usually the width of the parent element.

Comment: I think I understand that robert thanks a lot. Now is there any way to make the parent div have a fluid with then? would you mind put this as an answer so I can mark as correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parent container will already be a fluid width, because it's a `div` it will default to the full available width but you can explicitly limit that.  [This CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/sBzYH/2/) will make your two examples approximately the same size:

```
.container { 
    width: 66%; 
    min-width: 325px; 
}
```

If there's more than (just under) 500px available for the container then it will expand to take up 66% of the available space, but it will stay wide enough that the 30% width child element is always at least 100px wide.